# Entity framework and COM+

Tags: entity-framework, locking, com+

I have a problem using Entity Framework and COM+. The architecture is this:

- A windows service calls four methods of a COM, every n minutes.
- COM+ then calls the corresponding methods on a Business Layer.
- Business Layer calls DAL. DAL then returns a list to Business Layer. This is done by calling a `.ToList()`

When I try running the service, the DAL methods return a timeout inner exception. When I try to view the table from Enterprise Manager, it returns a timeout as well! From what I 've seen, the `SELECT` statements block the other connection instances.

Has anyone else experienced similar problems?

P.S. I cannot post any code yet because I am not at my work... Will do so tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as it seems, Entity Framework didn't have to do with any of the above.
As it turns out, the problem was within COM+. I should have ended each method of COM+ with ContextUtil.SetComplete(). Apparently, I didn't do that so the transaction stayed active and after the first few calls, it locked my db.

e.g.

```
Using MyEntity As New EntityObject
  MyEntity.Connection.Open()
   Dim rows = From tbl In MyEntity.MyTable _
              Select tbl
   list = rows.ToList
End Using

ContextUtil.SetComplete()
```

Please note that if an exception occurs, you should place a ContextUtil.SetAbort(). I should also like to note that the above code is mixed. It's part of my DAL layer and part of my COM+. I just put it like that to make the example more clear...